# Facebook Connect error: 1000

Tags: facebook, src

I get this following error when I am trying to integrate the fbconnect to my app.
I tried everything possible, but the error still continues. 
Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

> 2012-04-05 19:46:05.805 YBGreetings[12264:17603] yes granted
>   2012-04-05 19:46:17.035 YBGreetings[12264:17603] received response 
>   **2012-04-05 19:46:17.036 YBGreetings[12264:17603] Err message: (null)
>   2012-04-05 19:46:17.037 YBGreetings[12264:17603] Err code: 10000
>   2012-04-05 19:46:17.038 YBGreetings[12264:17603] Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x9131c90 {error={type = mutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>       2 : {contents = "type"} = {contents = "OAuthException"}
>       3 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
>       6 : {contents = "code"} = 2500**

Answer (score 0):

Extract from error log:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current use

So while doing query, consider to include `access token`